# CSS order section

Tags: css

I have this html:

```
<div class="footer-address">
    <section>Section 1 content</section>
    <section>Section 2 content</section>
</div>
```

Now, I want to make those sections into 2 columns **but** the last section should be shown on the left side and the first section should be shown on the right side.

Here is my css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    
    .footer-address {
        display : flex;
    }
    
    .footer-address section {
        column-count : 2;
    }
  
    .footer-address section p {
        margin-bottom : 0;
    }
}
```

**Now, it's on 2 columns but I want the last section should show on the left side instead of the right side.**

Answer (score 0):

you can set the [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) to `row-reverse`

```
.footer-address {
    display : flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Comment: could you check this footer: https://spa0001.alanvo.com/. I applied your CSS but no change. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: can you specify the part in detail? i can't find that section.

Comment: Its on the footer

Comment: facebook, linkedin, ... ?

Comment: i can see only one div inside `footer-address`.

Comment: you have any luck?

Comment: I am still trying

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-direction: row-reverse` in `.footer-address` 
Also keep in mind this is complete no sense in your case

```
.footer-address section {
   column-count : 2;
}
```

because `column-count` applies for every `section`, but you are willing to make each `section` inside `.footer-address` a separate column, not two separate section in **each** `section`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS grid to make your life a bit easier. Use `display: grid;` on your parent element and then you can give a grid template of two columns with `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`. Next, use `grid-column: 2;` on the second one to display it in the 2nd column

Comment: Style your parent as `.footer-address { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);}` Note the **fr** unit which stands for fraction. Then on you can style `section:nth-child(2) { grid-column: 2; }` Hope you understand.

Comment: applied but no luck :(*

Comment: May I see an image of the result?

Comment: CSS grid is a relatively modern technology, so test your code in the latest version of Google Chrome as I know for a fact that it works there.

Comment: I am using the latest chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Using order, no need to explain that to work you need to have parent with `display: flex` :

```css
 .footer-address section:first-child{
      order: 1;
    }
    .footer-address section:last-child{
      order: 2;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    
    .footer-address {
        display : flex;
    }
    
    .footer-address section {
        column-count : 2;
    }
  
    .footer-address section p {
        margin-bottom : 0;
    }
    .footer-address section:first-child{
      order: 2;
    }
    .footer-address section:last-child{
      order: 1;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-address">
    <section>Section 1 content</section>
    <section>Section 2 content</section>
</div>
```